# plot loss and accuracy of a model in keras

Tags: python, plot, keras

i have a function to build a model in keras such as below:

```
def build_model(lr = 0.0):
    inp = Input(shape = (max_len,))
    x = Embedding_layer
    y = LSTM_layer(x)
    y = Convolution_layer(y)
    x = GlobalMaxPooling1D(y)

    x = Dense(3, activation = "sigmoid")(x)
    model = Model(inputs = inp, outputs = x)
    model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = Adam(), metrics = ["accuracy"])
    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 256, epochs = 3, 
                        verbose = 1, callbacks = [ra_val, check_point, early_stop])
    model = load_model(file_path)
    return model

model = build_model(lr = 1e-3)
```

and now i want to plot history loss and accuracy after training phase, but model doesn't have history option.

how can i plot loss and accuracy ?

Answer (score 0):

The [fit](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) function will return a `History` object that contains the loss values and the metrics of the training.